# React JS: Ensure Progratimacally created input fields are unique from each other

Tags: html, reactjs, forms

I'm creating a form to seed a varying number of teams to a tournament, by first mapping them to a form group with labels and number input. How can I make it so each field has to be unique before the form is considered valid? 
By unique, I mean each field with take a certain number in a range, say if a tournament has 14 teams, then each field should be a number between 1 and 14, but two fields shouldn't be able to take the same number.

```
renderButton() {


            return (
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSeedingSubmit}>
                    {this.state.teams.map((team)=>
                        <FormGroup key={team.name}>
                            <Form.Label >{team.name}</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type = "number" name={team.name} min={1} max={this.state.tournament.noTeams} onChange={this.onChangeHandler} required />

                        </FormGroup>
                    )}
                    <Button type="submit" >
                       Submit
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            );
        }
```

On submit each team is being mapped with {name, seeding}. I want every team to have a unique seeding as they will be sorted into pools based on seeding later.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Unique in what sense?

Comment: Edited my question to clarify this. Basically each field will take a number in a range, I don't want to allow submission if any of the fields contain the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you can do is make the number inputs controlled by storing their values in the store:

```
state = {
  // other state,
  inputs: {}
}
```

then in `onChangeHandler` set the value of each input in the state:

```
function onChangeHandler(e) {
  const { name, value } = e.target;

  this.setState({
    inputs: {
      ...this.state.inputs,
      [name]: value
    }
  })
}
```

then when your form is submitted you can add a check to see if the values are unique or not, there are many ways to do that, what I'm doing here is remove the duplicates from the array and then check the length of the array against the values in the state like this:

```
function handleSeedingSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { inputs } = this.state;
  const valuesInState = Object.values(input);
  const uniqueValuesArr = [...new Set(valuesInState)];

  const areInputsValid = valuesInState.length === uniqueValuesArr.length;
  if (!areInputsValid) {
    // set Error here
    return;
  }

  // Hurray!! Inputs are valid
  // Handle Success case here
}
```

Hope it helps :)